# lvalue required as left operand of assignment(trying to set pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

What I want to do is set the value the pointer "points" at to char, like how you can set char to the value the pointer "points" at:

```
 char = (pointer - int);
```

but when I try this:

```
(pointer - int) = char;
```

I get the error

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're "trying to accomplish"??? The above is not valid C syntax in any conceivable manner! For comparison, use `==` (and you'll need to do some casting in order to get it compiled).

Comment: `(pointer - int)` is not an lvalue, it is just some spot in memory `int` bytes below `pointer`. To place a value at that address `*(pointer - int)` is closer to making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to set the character location a few to the left of the one pointed to by your pointer, you'd need something like this:

```
char string[] = "Hello, world!";
printf("%s\n", string);            /* original string */
char *pointer = &string[12];       /* points to the ! */
int offset = 5;                    /* w is 5 to the left of ! */
*(pointer - offset) = 'W';         /* changes world to World */
printf("%s\n", string);            /* see the result */
```

If this is what you were trying to do, you might also like to learn that this sort of thing is at the heart of the "equivalence between arrays and pointers" in C.  You could also write the character-changing expression as

```
pointer[-offset] = 'W';            /* changes world to World */
```

and this would do exactly the same thing.  (In fact, by definition, for any array or pointer `p` and any offset `o`, the subscript expression `p[o]` is exactly equivalent to `*(p + o)`.)